# How to achieve camera switch function, and use it in later recognition?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a project to use the webcam at phone or laptop to do the object recognition. Right now I can get the camera id and object recognition, but I can't switch the video source to the camera that I want. Could someone please help me or give me some hints that how I can select the camera I want, and then use it to do the object recognition? Thanks a lot!

```js
var classifier; var resultsP; var msg1; var prevmsg; var video
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const select = document.getElementById('select');
let currentStream;

function voice_testing(){
    var voice_message = "Voice triggered";
    var message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(voice_message);
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(message);
}

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
    classifier = ml5.imageClassifier('MobileNet', video, modelReady);
    resultsP = createP('Loading model and video...');
}

function modelReady() {
    console.log('Model Ready');
    classifyVideo();
}
function classifyVideo() {
    classifier.classify(gotResult);
}
async function gotResult(err, results) {
    resultsP.html(results[0].label + ' ' + nf(results[0].confidence, 0, 2));
    if(nf(results[0].confidence, 0, 2) > 0.2){
        if(results[0].label != prevmsg){
            msg1 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(results[0].label);
            msg2 = results[0].label.split(',');
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg1);
            Text = msg2[0];
            letters = Text.split('');
            letters1 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(letters);
            window.speechSynthesis.speak(letters1);
            prevmsg = results[0].label;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(classifyVideo, 8000);
}

function stopMediaTracks(stream) {
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
    track.stop();
  });
}

function gotDevices(mediaDevices) {
  select.innerHTML = '';
  select.appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
  let count = 1;
  mediaDevices.forEach(mediaDevice => {
    if (mediaDevice.kind === 'videoinput') {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = mediaDevice.deviceId;
      const label = mediaDevice.label || `Camera ${count++}`;
      const textNode = document.createTextNode(label);
      option.appendChild(textNode);
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
  });
}

button.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (typeof currentStream !== 'undefined') {
    stopMediaTracks(currentStream);
  }
  const videoConstraints = {};
  if (select.value === '') {
    videoConstraints.facingMode = 'environment';
  } else {
    videoConstraints.deviceId = { exact: select.value };
  }
  const constraints = {
    video: videoConstraints,
    audio: false
  };
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(stream => {
      currentStream = stream;
      video.srcObject = stream;
      return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
    })
    .then(gotDevices)
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
});

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(gotDevices);
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.startButton {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Camera selection</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.4.3/dist/ml5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Webcam Object Recognition</h1>
  </header>

  <main>
      <button id="button">Get camera</button>
      <select id="select">
        <option></option>
      </select>
    <button id="startButtonID" onclick="voice_testing();">Voice Testing</button>
    </br>
    <p>If no voice, click the button</p>
    <p>You can select the camera you want from the box above, and click get camera button</p>
  </main>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

ks a lot!